# How can I capture certain data using regex if it is dependent on another field?

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing, regex-greedy, rubular

I need help in writing regex for the below mentioned log:

`URLReputation: Risk unknown, URL: http://facebook.com`

I wrote a regex like below:

`URLReputation\:\s*(.*?),\s*URL\:\s*(.*)`

Here everything is working. But in case URL isn't there, the URLReputation also will not be captured.

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: Where does the string end when "URL isn't there"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the non greedy `.*?` into a negated character class `[^,]+` and match any char except a comma. Then make the URL part optional using an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?`

You want to capture the value of a url using `.*` but that could possibly also match an empty string.

You might make the pattern more specific by matching at least a single non whitespace char `\S+` or use a pattern like for example specifying the start `https?://\S+`

```
URLReputation:\s*([^,]+)(?:,\s*URL:\s*(\S+))?
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/vIqaWA9TZ1q0O2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string ends immediately before the comma when the "URL isn't there", you can simply put the comma and what follows in an optional non-capture group and add an end-of-line anchor:

```
/URLReputation: +(.*?)(?:, +URL:\ +(.*))?$/
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/VeMgDKavVg5Es9)

Mainly to improve readability, I changed each `\s` to a space as it appears that spaces are the only whitespace characters you wish to match.